# What model names should be prefixed with

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, naming

I'm having an issue with naming of my types, generally it applies to all of my projects.

I'm working with CQRS and many times i have different layers of my application that refer to similar 'context' of a data.
For example i have a Player context which is spread across query model, write model, domain model etc.

Basically my question is that if some class/struct/data type is referring to specifically 'Query' type, should i name it as PlayerQuery or QueryPlayer.

From my understanding the 'PlayerQuery' implies that it is a query of a player data, on the other hand 'QueryPlayer' implies some kind of 'Query' behavior.

It has been quite a while when i started coding but i still struggle with properly naming things.

It feels like the 'PlayerQuery' is better approach here.
Are there any books or online resources where i could tackle this issue?
Thanks much

Comment: Your query name's should be name of your desired use case.
For example: `FetchPlayerBasicInfo`, `PaginateListOfTop10Players`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It has been quite a while when i started coding but i still struggle with properly naming things.*

A great quote that is relevant here  :

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

You are having this problem because you are trying to approach the problem with a `CRUD` mindset, whereas CQRS (or CQS) advocates focusing on the actual interaction. Even when different parts of the application share player context, the reason for its usage will be different.

As examples, you will be:

- Querying for a paginated list of players
- Asking for a single player's detail
- Saving an individual player's data
- Bulk-updating an attribute in multiple player details

In each of these interactions, you should take the interaction itself as a cue to name the Query/Command/DTO object.

So the data class names could be:

- PlayersList
- PlayerDetailForQuery
- PlayerDetailForSave
- PlayerDetailsForBulkUpdate

An improvement would be to suffix each class name with the type of object:

- PlayersList**Params**
- PlayersList**Result**
- Player**Row** (or) Player**Item** (or) Player**Detail**
- Player**Event**
- Player**Specification**

The best implementation would be to combine the interaction with the type of object:

- FetchPlayerList**Params**
- FetchPlayerList**Result**
- GetPlayer**Detail**
- BulkUpdatePlayer**Params**
- SavePlayer**Command**
- PlayerSaved**Event**

The most important thing is, once you choose a convention (like **Detail** instead of **Item** or **Row**), be consistent in its usage all over the code.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, the `Detail`, `Params` and `Result` suffixes helped.
I'm a bit skeptical about the Event and Command ones though, they are really tight with the command/write model so i try to keep them as short as i can, the 'ed' for me already ensures that it is an event. 
For the commands, not sure about one thing though, i name them by first introducing the model eg `PlayerCreate`, `PlayerChange` instead behavior-first `CreatePlayer` that is my root isue, which one looks more clean. When i have lots of commands its easier to filter them by introducing the model first.

Comment: On your first comment, I usually suffix `Command` because I have a DTO with the same name associated with the action, like `CreatePlayerDTO` and `CreatePlayerCommand`. Suffixing the type of class also helps me look for a cluster of Classes that work together as part of a command or query. On your second comment, I usually prefer `CreatePlayer` instead of `PlayerCreate` because that's what would be present in Ubiquitous language. That's how the domain expert would express the action, and it's better to have the code model the exact phrase.